# "Member 'HttpClient' is declared in another module and needs to be imported" in Mono.Cecil / Fody

Tags: c#, exception, mono, mono.cecil, fody

and thanks for giving me your time.

### Background

I'm trying to create a new HttpClient in Mono.Cecil, and to add it to a field.
Here's my code:

```
TypeDefinition HttpClientDef = ModuleDefinition.GetType(typeof(HttpClient)).Resolve();
TypeDefinition def = GetSomeTypeDefinitionFromModule();

FieldDefinition field = new FieldDefinition($"${GENERATED_CLIENT_PATH}", FieldAttributes.Private, HttpClientDef);
def.Fields.Add(field);
```

No problem here, but once `void Execute()` has returned, an exception is thrown: **Member 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' is declared in another module and needs to be imported**.

### So what?

I cannot import `HttpClient`. I've tried many things, and here's what I know:

- ModuleDefinition doesn't have a definition for `System.Uri` or `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, for example.
- I can, however, get a reference to `HttpClient` by doing:

  ```
  AssemblyDefinition httpAssembly = AssemblyResolver.Resolve("System.Net.Http");
  TypeDefinition HttpClientDef = httpAssembly.MainModule.GetType(typeof(HttpClient)); // fyi, HttpClient is also in httpAssembly.GetTypes().
  ```
- Once I have a valid `TypeDefinition`, I have no idea what to do with it.

  - `ModuleDefinition.Import(def).Resolve()` does not change anything ;
  - `new TypeReference(namespace, name, ModuleDefinition, httpAssembly.Name)` doesn't work either ;
  - Neither does calling `def` directly.

Any idea?

Thank you,
Greg.

---

#### Edit 1

Turns out you can't import a type if its reference (in this case `System.Net.Http`) isn't used in the code.
Now, I can load it using `TypeDefinition def = ModuleDefinition.GetType(typeof(HttpClient))`.

Comment: What version of Mono.Cecil are you using? In my version `ModuleDefinition.Import(...)` (all overloads) is marked obsolete, replaced by `ImportReference(...)`.

Comment: My version doesn't have the `Import` method marked obsolete, although I did see the blog post about this. Did you get it from Nuget as well, or did you compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `System` and `System.Net.Http` weren't referenced, even though I had added 'em as references. Explicitly using `HttpClient` once in my (modified) code forced the reference to exist, and I was able to `Import` it after that.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new `FieldDefinition` requires only a `TypeReference` not a `TypeDefinition`, so there is no need to call `Resolve()`. Try this:

```
FieldDefinition field = 
    new FieldDefinition($"${GENERATED_CLIENT_PATH}",
    FieldAttributes.Private, 
    moduleDefn.Import(typeof(HttpClient));
```